# How to make the "Web Address" link in List Settings clickable

Tags: 2010, list, hyperlink, settings

On the "List Settings" page of any custom list that we make (or OOTB list for that matter), there are 3 fields that show at the top at all times: "Name", "Web Address", and "Description" (sample screenshot below)

[image]

My question is regarding the "Web Address" meta-field, which shows the URL of the list in question that you are editing settings for (always with the "AllItems.aspx" view).

That is all well and good, but I'd like to know if there's a way to make this URL clickable for all list settings pages, like a hyperlink, instead of having to highlight that text and paste it into a browser window. Maybe even make it open in a new window with `target="_blank"`.

This would make it more convenient to work with the list so we can save a little bit of time (however small it may be) and for efficiency (and it's just a general annoyance). I haven't found any setting to control this. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If I am in list settings then I generally use the breadcrumb to get to the list when I am finished.  If you cannot see the breadcrumb then it sounds like it has been removed from your master page?

As for making this link clickable, other then a code solution you may be able to do it with some jQuery - but this sounds like a lot of effort when a breadcrumb would also make a lot of other things easier.

EDIT - added details from page and master page.

This is an extract from a standard list All Items page.  Note that it is placing content into the PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="TitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <span class="ms-ltviewselectormenuheader" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:ListTitleViewSelectorMenu AlignToParent="true" id="LTViewSelectorMenu" runat="server" />
            </span>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
```

This is an extract from the standard v4.master:

```
<h2>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
</h2>
```

So the master page is creating a placeholder and the page itself is populating that placeholder.

If you are not seeing the breadcrumb then it would suggest that somebody has customised either the master page or the CSS to hide the content of that placeholder.

Comment: We have the breadcrumbs showing, but the farthest down it goes is to the Site level that the list resides in. Is it supposed to be more granular than this? I would accept either a code solution or jQuery, but the question is how to apply it to the list settings page of every list (i.e. where would the code be applied to?)

Comment: Yes, you can change the granularity of your breadcrumb in your master page - I think it will have the be applied to your system pages.  If you decide on a jQuery solution then that would also need to be added to the master page which is applied to your system pages.

Comment: So I am trying to find what to add to the end of the breadcrumb links in the master page, and so far the lowest it goes is the property "CurrentNodeStyle", which seems to be the Site level breadcrumb. What is the property for the list-level breadcrumb?

Comment: Updated response above with more detail.

Comment: Yes, our master page was heavily customized by a 3rd party, which is why our breadcrumbs are also custom and don't show all the way down to the list level. I will try to re-insert the placeholder as you have shown. Thank you Dave!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I agree your points Mr.Dave Paylor.

Alex, you can use the breadcrumb for navigating the list's default "Allitems" view.
Otherwise, please set the link as quick launch in the left hand side of your site. By using the quick launch also you can easily navigate.

Please find the both option's screen shots:

1.Breadcrumb

[image]

2.Quick Launch

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but we are currently not using the quick launch per business requirements, so it is being hidden. The currently viable solution would be to add the list link back into the breadcrumb trail.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, the breadcrumbs as you have shown are not available since we have a customized breadcrumb list (not by us).